# create a list of objects and call the same function on each of them

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm currently working on a project for dns-enumeration, which sends requests to various APIs.
Each of the APIs is handeled in its own class, so now i got 22-something classes, which all provide a ".query(string: domain, boolean: dnsprobe)" function, which handles the request to the API and the processing of the data it recieved.

For example, this is what the ".query()" function looks like for "alienvault" (all the functions inherit from "Source", a class i build to be able to pass a config_obj if needed):

```
class Alienvault(Source):
    @staticmethod
    def query(domain, dnsprobe):
        url = 'https://otx.alienvault.com/api/v1/indicators/domain/' + domain + '/passive_dns'
        fqdns = []

        start = timer()

        try:
            req = urllib.request.Request(url)
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
            data = response.read()
            json_data = json.loads(data)

            passive_dns = json_data['passive_dns']

            for item in passive_dns:
                if item['hostname'] not in fqdns:
                    if item['hostname'].endswith(domain):
                        fqdns.append(item['hostname'])

        except urllib.error.HTTPError as error:
            print("[" + colored(u'\u0021', 'red') + "] AlienVault: " + str(error.code) + " " + error.reason)

        end = timer()
        exec_time = round((end - start), 3)

        # check if domains still exist
        probed_fqdns = []
        if dnsprobe:
            probed_fqdns = probe_fqdns(fqdns)

        return Stats("AlienVault", domain, fqdns, probed_fqdns, exec_time)
```

All of the classes follow the same pattern, but every API needs to be handeled different, e.g. the query function works different.

In my main file, i now want to create an instance of every class and call the function on every of the created objects to store all API-Data in a list.

I guess there is a better way than what i'm currently doing:

```
check_alienvault = True
check_Binaryedge = True
check_Bufferover = True
...

domain = 'hackertarget.com'
dnsprobe = False

if check_Alienvault:
  Alienvault_obj = sources.Alienvault()
  ret = Alienvault_obj.query(domain, dnsprobe)
  return_values.append(ret)

if Binaryedge:
  Binaryedge_obj = sources.Binaryedge()
  ret = Binaryedge_obj.query(domain, dnsprobe)
  return_values.append(ret)

if Bufferover:
  ...
```

as i need to do this for all of the 22 APIs separately, which leads to a lot of boilerplate code ?

As i'm not as good in python programming as i would like to be, i'm struggling solving this problem on my own and would be thankful for any advancing input.

Comment: `query` is a `static method`. I don't think you need to create an object. You can call the `method` directly.

Comment: some of the APis rely on API-Keys, which i safe in a config file, which is created on __init__, so i need to create an object to be able to access the config

Comment: In static method you can't access the `self`, how can you access the parameters from `init`

Comment: the example i posted doesnt need an API-Key, thats why i made it static, i chose that one for better unterstanding, as handling the config in certain cases is not my problem, but the reason why i use that class structure